# Import eclipse project into android studio, apk size is Increased

Tags: android, android-studio

I was converted eclipse project into android studio project, apk size is increased 10mb to 17mb. I don't how to resolve this my grade file look like this,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'

    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }


        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    android {
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        }
    }
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to get original size of my apk file thank you

Comment: set minifyEnabled to true and generate APK in release mode, some size will be decreased.

Comment: @Krishna There is no size changes in my apk, same result having 17 mb

Comment: do that in the buildType->debug

Answer (score 0):

Focus on this line:

```
compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
```

It is the robotium jar,should not be compiled in build config debug/release.

Try modify it to 'androidTestCompile'.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.4'
```

Comment: I changed like your post but i have an error [Error:(15, 25) error: package com.robotium.solo does not exist].

Comment: Have you combined your robotium test code in your main project?When you are using eclipse,these are two projects,right?   I recommend you to separate these two projects. You can check the example for robitium here:https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/wiki/Downloads. @Manoj

Comment: yeh absolutely correct, if i separated like eclipse but how can i test my project using robotium in android studio